# Описание как тип речи

Tags: описание

В ответах утверждается, что в данном тексте содержится **описание**. Кто-то может пояснить, в каких именно фразах оно содержится? Для меня описание - это причастия и прилагательные. Тут лишь в одном предложении их можно найти, но авторы говорят о том, что описание содержится в предложениях 4-7.
Или подразумевается, что оно есть среди данных предложений?

> И пахло в нем так же: гарью, трупами, пылью. Меж изуродованных домов
> по улицам, заваленным ломью, кружило листву, бумагу, сажу. Над городом
> мрачно стоял купол пожара. Он слабел, опускался к домам, проваливался
> в улицы и переулки, дробился на усталые кострища

Answer (score 0):

> 1.Последней военной осенью я стоял на посту возле пушек в небольшом,
> разбитом польском городе.2. Это был первый иностранный город, который я
> видел в своей жизни.3. Он ничем не отличался от разрушенных городов
> России.4. И пахло в нем так же: гарью, трупами, пылью.5. Меж изуродованных
> домов по улицам, заваленным ломью, кружило листву, бумагу, сажу.6. Над
> городом мрачно стоял купол пожара.7. Он слабел, опускался к домам,
> проваливался в улицы и переулки, дробился на усталые кострища.8. Но
> раздавался долгий, глухой взрыв, купол подбрасывало в темное небо, и
> все вокруг озарялось тяжелым багровым светом. 9. Листья с деревьев
> срывало, кружило жаром вверху, и там они истлевали.

1. Я стоял на посту где? - повествование.\
2. Иностранный город, который я видел? Что я видел? - тоже повествование\
3. Он ничем не отличался от других городов России. Что необычного в этом городе?  - тоже повествование, если бы отчаялся и почему, то было бы рассуждение.\
4. Пахло в нём как, какой запах? - описание. *Запах горелый, трупный, пыльный.*~
5. Какие были дома, какой был вид в воздухе? - описание. *Изуродованные*(переносное), *заваленный ломью* ~ захламленный, разрушенный, "кружило листву, бумагу, сажу" - картины разрушений.
6. *Мрачный стоял купол пожара* - образная фигура речи, описание.
7. Тоже образное описание пожара. Какой пожар? *Усталые* кострища, он *слабел, опускался, проваливался, дробился* - олицетворения и метафоры.
8. Вроде как про какой-то взрыв, что происходило - что-то между описанием и повествованием. Про взрыв можно поставить: когда раздавался взрыв.
9. Вроде про листья, которые в итоге истлевали - повествование, но тоже с описанием. Хотя 8-9 тоже не конкретно и метафорично. *Кружило жаром вверху* - всё такие ближе к фактическому обстоятельству догорания в огре листьев.

**Описание** - это создание атмосферы, как это было или какой, какая какие? Нет фактов и мало конкретики. Образный речь, метафоры.

**Повествование** - что было, с кем, когда, при каких обстоятельствах, сколько, рассказы о фактах и тп.

А **рассуждение** - почему или зачем, выводы.

[Типы текстов.](https://foxford.ru/wiki/russkiy-yazyk/tipi-textov-sravnenie)

Comment: Он слабел, опускался к домам, проваливался в улицы и переулки, дробился на усталые кострища. Тут действия, а не статика.

Comment: @ТатьянаАлексеевна Ну да, но это все очень неконкретно, как пожар "проваливался"? - олицетворение. То есть это не прямые действия, а образные. Если образная речь. "глаголы в форме несовершенного вида прошедшего и настоящего времени
слова в переносном значении, сравнение" - с Фоксфорда, то что относится к описанию. То есть все по теории.

Comment: "Глаголы в форме прошедшего времени" и в повествовании есть.

Comment: и этот фоксфорд - фигня какая-то. Написано, что "сравнение" - элемент описания, а оно всегда к рассуждению относилось.

Comment: @ТатьянаАлексеевна  глаголы в форме несовершенного вида прошедшего и настоящего времени слова **в переносном значении**. Хорошо, предположим это повествование, что произошло в этих предложениях?

Comment: Не думаю, что не найдется нное количество примеров повествования, где были бы глаголы несовершенного вида.

Comment: Пожар из большой кучил превратился в остатки пыли, распластавшись по улицам.

Comment: В повествовании чаще других встречаются глагольные формы совершенного вида, позволяющие называть последовательные действия. Однако для придания большей выразительности могут быть употреблены и глаголы прошедшего времени несовершенного вида, позволяющие выделить одно из действий, подчеркнуть его длительность

Comment: Пожар из большой кучил превратился в остатки пыли, распластавшись по улицам. - так это не повествование про пожар, а описание сгоревшего города.

Comment: Согласитесь, что "опускался, дробился"- это не то же самое, что находился, стоял, ощущался, витал. В первых двух глагол есть процесс.

Comment: До этого шло описание, а потом повествование про пожар, я так считаю.

Comment: Опускался и дробился - это косвенные признаки, уже произошедшего, предположение о произошедшем. А повествование - это когда очевидец рассказывает про события.

Comment: Зачем описывать действия? Если они выражают суть?

Comment: В этом предложении действует пожар.

Comment: Если сначала он был сильным, обширным, то к концу он распался на части. Это ли не действия?

Comment: Повествование - это прямой текст. А описание - это через что-то, описание сгоревшего города через образы пожара. Пожар да, но речь вообще не о пожаре, а о картинах сгоревших зданий в разрушенном городе. Картины последствий войны.

Comment: Нельзя учитывать контекст, мы же говорим о конкретном предложении. О действиях

Comment: Почему нельзя учитывать контекст? И второе, глаголы в переносном значении. Если бы это было повествование, было бы время, конкретизация места и последствий. Есть кусок текста, о чём текст? О пожаре? нет, о городе, о человеке который в город приехал, а пожар - это уже описательные моменты.